# How to show the Tor Browser, again the menu items that are hidden compared to the esr version?

Tags: configuration, firefox, tor-install, browsers, javascript

The Tor Browser is based on a Firefox-esr browser.
Source: https://www.linux-magazin.de/news/kritische-luecken-in-firefox-esr-thunderbird-und-tor-browser/

With the Tor Browser, some menu items that are available in Firefox-esr are hidden. How can the hidden menu items be shown again so that they can be used when needed?

Examples of menu items that are hidden in the Tor Browser are:

- cookies, accepting 3rd party cookies, accepting DRM video protection, accepting javascript and so on.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for IP address "obfuscation" rather than anonymity, you could run Tor standalone and take a normal firefox and set it's proxy settings to the socks port of Tor.

If you're on windows, download the "Tor expert bundle" https://www.torproject.org/download/tor/

Configure torrc to have a socks port, run Tor, configure firefox to the set socks port, success.

But remember, Tor isn't for streaming videos. You won't have fun with buffering and strain the network unnecessarily for other users. Get a vpn for that.

Comment: I didn't ask for, but that's an interesting answer. Do you know a link to a how to for this ?